# sqlsrv connect to sql server whil Mysqli_connect doesn't

Tags: php, sql-server, mysqli, sqlsrv

Hello I am new at this,

But i have created 2 different cods onw with sqlsrv and it connects to sql server 2012

but when i create another php code with mysqli it returns with an error, any idea why?

First code with sqlsrv :

```
$connect = array( "UID" => "admin", "PWD" => "admin2017", "Database" => "sunto" );
$link = sqlsrv_connect( "localhost", $connect );
if( $link ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
} else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ) );
}
```

another code with mysqli_connect :

```
<?php


$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin2017";

$databaseName = "sunto";

$dbConnected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

$dbSelected = mysqli_select_db($dbConnected, $databaseName);


?>
```

It shows the below error !!

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it. in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\index3.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index3.php on line 12

Comment: Mysql and ms sql are different servers

Comment: Yes I know but both extensions installed and I though mysqli is fine with mss sql server, Am I wrong?

Comment: mysqli as the name implies is for mysql probably it uses the mysqlnd. You might wanna look at PDO. It supports many db

Comment: what's server type is this running on? By server I mean Wamp, Xampp, Mamp etc. a

Comment: there are too many possible duplicates; you will need to Google the error and consult the many questions and answers.

Comment: YES, you are wrong

Answer (score -1):

Find mysqli in your php.ini(xampp->php->php.ini) configuration file.
you can find **;extension=php_mysqli.dll** in that file. Uncomment(extension=php_mysqli.dll) this one and try the code as like as below.

```
<?php

     @session_start();
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "your_username";
     $password = "your_password";
     $dbname = "your_dbname";
     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }
?>
```